# Use functions: uc_file_user_downloads function and theme function

Tags: ubercart

I would like to print files user download from ubercart on  a new page. I find this theme function "uc_file_user_downloads" but i don't know how to use it.

To print the table i write this little code:

```
<?php 

 print $user->uid;
 $account = $GLOBALS['user'];
 print theme('uc_file_user_downloads', $account);
?>
```

And the result i have:

> 26 Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
>   /code/includes/theme.inc
>   on line 1070

Could you explain me the correct way to pass the parameter on this function. I tried to cast the stdclass to array but this is not working.

Comment: Have you tried `print uc_file_user_downloads($account);` instead of `print theme('uc_file_user_downloads', $account);`. As `uc_file_user_downloads` is table builder function so I guess it doesn't need to be passed to theme function.

Comment: drupal 6 or drupal 7?

Comment: I it's on Drupal 7. If I use directly print uc_file_user_downloads($account); then i have this error : 1 Fatal error: Call to undefined function uc_file_user_downloads()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is drupal 6 in order to print the  table you can simply do [`print uc_file_user_downloads($account);`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ubercart!uc_file!uc_file.pages.inc/function/uc_file_user_downloads/6) ,this function will internally call the theme function [`theme_uc_file_user_downloads`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/theme_uc_file_user_downloads/6)

What you are trying in your code is combination of both.So in drupal 6 try witih the following code.

```
global $user;
print uc_file_user_downloads($user);
```

In drupal 7 the function [`uc_file_user_downloads($account);`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/uc_file_user_downloads/7) returns array unlike html in drupal 6. So try the following with drupal 7

```
module_load_include('inc', 'uc_file', 'uc_file.pages');
global $user;
$table = uc_file_user_downloads($user);
print drupal_render($table['downloads']);
```

Comment: If i try the second option for drupal 7 i have this error : Fatal error: Call to undefined function uc_file_user_downloads() in /code/profiles/commons/themes/contrib/ifr/templates/panels/panels-pane--block--block-2.tpl.php on line 72

Comment: @Antonio try with updated codes

Comment: thanks so much. I was searching how to include the inc file in php!! I have learned something new today !! Thank you so much

Comment: Just to know. Why using theme function was incorrect in this case ? When use theme function and When use table builder function ?  http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/theme_uc_file_user_downloads/7 how could i use this function then ?

Comment: @Antonio the reason theme function was not working was simply because of the reason that it expects $files as Associative array of downloadable files,and table header and you were trying to call the theme function with account object, so that is the reason I said before you  are trying combination of both